# Receive a map from Navigator.pop

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page where user enters his username and birthday after initial sign in, then I want to return and use this data in previous screen.

In Screen2:

```
Navigator.pop(context, {'username':username, 'birthday':birthday});
```

In Screen1:

```
final userData = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/setup_profile');
```

final/var works well for single variable such as String but doesn't work for maps because it doesn't know returning object is actually a map.

Naturally you can't use `userData['username']` without specifying it is a Map and I don't understand how to specify it.

I've tried

```
Map<String, dynamic> userData = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
```

It didn't work I received this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Route<Map<String, dynamic>>'
```

Then I tried

```
Route route = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
Map<String, dynamic> data = route.currentResult;
```

This didn't work as well, I got same error

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Route<Route<dynamic>>'
```

Simply put I want to use that returned Map in Screen1.

Main problem is I don't know how to specify returning data, is it a custom class or map or list or something else. How can I specify return type from Navigator.pop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Navigator.pop()` allows you to provide an optional generic typed argument.

A good practice to properly pass arguments using the `Navigator`, not just for the `.pop()` method, is by creating page/screen argument objects.

**screen1.dart**

```dart
class Screen1Arguments {
  Map<String, dynamic> someMapVariable;

  Screen1Arguments(this.someMapVariable);
}
```

Based on your setup, you can now retrieve the value from `Screen2` from `Screen1` like this:

**screen1.dart**

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Open Second Screen'),
  onPressed: () async {
    final Screen1Arguments args = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Screen2(),
      ),
    );
    print("args ${args.someMapVariable}");
  },
),
```

Given that now you are using `Screen1Arguments` as your typed argument for the `.pop()` method, you can now conveniently pass `Map` variables in your `Screen2`:

**screen2.dart**

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Close Screen'),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(
      context,
      Screen1Arguments(
        {
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2",
          "key3": 3,
        },
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

In addition, you can still add other variables with different data types (aside from `Map`) just like any other model classes or objects you have in your app:

```dart
class Screen1Arguments {
  Map<String, dynamic> someMapVariable;
  String username;
  Date birthday;

  Screen1Arguments(this.someMapVariable, this.username, this.birthday);
}
```

**Further reading**

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html
- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast to a `Map` after getting the result. Something like this:

```
final userData = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/setup_profile');
print((userData as Map<String, dynamic>)['username']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution work for me i just send a map using POP() function and get that map as follow below.You just need to cast the returned value in a MAP.

```
`        Map<String, dynamic> myData = new Map();
         myData["object1"] = object1;
         myData["object2"] = object2;
         Navigator.pop(context,myData);

         Navigator.of(viewService.context).pushNamed(
            PageKeys.foodDetailsPage,
            arguments: {
              "userMeal": state.userMeal,
              "food": food,
            },
            ).then((onValue) {
              //getting a map from POP() function
                Map<String, dynamic> myData = onValue;
                Object1 = myData["Object1"];
                Object2 = myData["Object2"];
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

screen1.dart

```dart
void selectedAdressLatLang(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/MapsLocation').then((value) {
      Map<String, double> result = {};
      result = value;

      print(result['addresslat'].toString());
      print(result['addressLang'].toString());
    });
  }
```

screen2.dart

```dart
void sendDataBack(BuildContext context) {
      Navigator.pop(
        context,
        {"addresslat": addresslat, "addressLang": addressLang},
      );
  }
```

Access the returned values by then using and converting the value to a map

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. It works as expected.